# P=NP turns 50. 1971 STOC conference

Tags: np-complete, p-vs-np, history

Stephen Cook presented his seminal paper "The complexity of theorem-proving procedures" at the 1971 STOC (Symposium on Theory of Computing) conference which was held May 3-5, 1971 at Case Western. How rapidly was this recognized as being revolutionary? The book "Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness" by Garey and Johnson, published in 1979, begins with the lines

> Few technical terms have gained such rapid notoriety as the appelation
> "NP-complete." In the short time since its introduction in the early
> 1970's, this term has come to symbolize the abyss of inherent
> intractability that algorithm designers increasingly face as they seek
> to solve larger and more complex problems.

This suggests that it was rapidly recognized as being revolutionary. Furthermore, the [Wikipedia article on NP-completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) contains the following tidbit:

> The concept of NP-completeness was introduced in 1971 (see Cook–Levin
> theorem), though the term NP-complete was introduced later. At the
> 1971 STOC conference, there was a fierce debate between the computer
> scientists about whether NP-complete problems could be solved in
> polynomial time on a deterministic Turing machine. John Hopcroft
> brought everyone at the conference to a consensus that the question of
> whether NP-complete problems are solvable in polynomial time should be
> put off to be solved at some later date, since nobody had any formal
> proofs for their claims one way or the other. This is known as "the
> question of whether P=NP".

Unfortunately, there is no reference given in the Wikipedia article, and I have been unable to find any discussion (beyond that) of the conference itself. For example, [Cook's Turing Award Lecture](https://amturing.acm.org/award_winners/cook_n991950.cfm), which would be a natural place for reminiscences, contains no such discussion.

Does anyone know of any references which discuss the 1971 STOC conference in detail? I am mostly interested in the "fierce debate" that the Wikipedia article mentions, although an actual conference program which gives the exact date of Cook's talk would also be interesting. It would be fun to mention it in class next week.